# System of First Order ODE with non-constant coeddicients

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I am wondering if it is possible to solve the following system of ODEs. Would it be possible to use matrix exponential in the way it was used [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68409/system-of-ode-with-non-constant-coefficient-matrix/68424#68424?newreg=a1c01ccbab1248dc88bd8d6cc252945c)?

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{1}(t) \\
   a_{2}(t)\\
  \end{array} } \right]^{'} = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & \frac{H_{12}}{i\hbar}cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}) \\
   \frac{H_{12}}{i\hbar}cos(\frac{2\pi t}{T}) & \frac{\Delta E}{i \hbar} \\
  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{1}(t) \\
   a_{2}(t)\\
  \end{array} } \right]$$