# General solution of $\dot{x} = A(t) x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This is a very basic question, but I'm having trouble solving this.

Let $A(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function, and consider the linear diferential equation

$$ \dot{x} = A(t) x$$
$$x(0) = x_0,$$

where $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ are the linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n.$

I'm wondering if $ \exp \left (\int_ {0}^{t} A (s) ds \right) x_0 $ is a solution of the above differential equation. As far as I know this is only valid when $A(t) = A_0$, and I could not find any book that says this result is true.

---

**NB:** If we pretend that life is beautiful and things work as we would like
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\exp \left (\int_ {0}^{t} A (s) ds \right) x_0 \right) &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{0}^{t} A(s) ds\right) \left(\exp \left(\int_ {0}^{t} A (s) ds \right)\right) x_0\\
&= A(t) \left(\exp \left(\int_ {0}^{t} A (s) ds \right)\right) x_0.
\end{align*}

But I am not very sure of such manipulations.

Comment: But life *is* beautiful!

Comment: When $B(t),B'(t)$ don't commute then $\frac{d}{dt} B(t)^k = \sum_{j=1}^k B(t)^{j-1} B'(t) B^{k-j}$ thus $\frac{d}{dt}  e^{B(t)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \frac{d}{dt} B^k=  \sum_{n \ge 0, m \ge 0} \frac{B(t)^n B'(t) B(t)^m}{(n+m+1)!}$ is a mess

Comment: @reuns then,  is $\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t} A(s) ds\right) x_0 $  the solution only when $A(t)$ and $\int_{0}^{t} A(s)ds$ commute ?

Comment: I meant when everything commute ie. $A(t),A(s)$ commute for every $s,t$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68409/system-of-ode-with-non-constant-coefficient-matrix and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158170/general-systems-of-linear-differential-equations-with-variable-coefficients

Comment: @BadamBaplan But not *so* beautiful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of such differential equation is called time ordered exponential:

$$
x(t) = \mathrm{Texp} \left ( \int_0^t A(s) ds \right ) x(0).
$$

The definition of the $\mathrm{Texp}$ can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential).

The expression of the $\mathrm{Texp}$ can be obtained in the following way. Integrate both sides of the ODE to get

$$
x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t A(s) x(s) ds
$$

Now the above can be iterated taking care that operators $A(t)$ at different times do not commute.