# Using $\text{SL}(2)$ to solve $2\times2$ linear system of ODEs of order 1 with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebra

Define the matrix $A(t)=\begin{pmatrix} - p(t) & 1 \\ -1 & p(t) \end{pmatrix}$ where $t$ is a real variable and $p$ a function of $t$.

Looking for solutions $u=(u_1(t),u_2(t))$ to the equation $$ \frac{d}{dt} u = A(t) u $$ we need to use [time ordered exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500831/general-solution-of-dotx-at-x?noredirect=1&lq=1), because $[A(t_1),A(t_2)]\neq 0$; since $A$ is written in terms of generators of $\text{SL}(2)$ algebra, I would [expect](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158170/general-systems-of-linear-differential-equations-with-variable-coefficients) that in this case the solution can still have a simple explicit form, but cannot work it out. Is there any hint or reference that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate one of the variables, "reducing" to a second-order equation

$$ \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} u_1(t) +(p'(t)-p(t)^2+1)u_1(t) = 0 $$

Since $p'(t) - p(t)^2 + 1$ is essentially arbitrary, I don't think there is a simple explicit form in general.  Even in a case as simple as $p(t) = 1+t^3$, Maple doesn't find a closed form solution.